# Change role after purchasing a specific product on WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to add a function which changes the user’s role after purchasing a specific product (by ID, or category). How can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'misha_change_role_on_purchase' );

function misha_change_role_on_purchase( $order_id ) {

// get order object and items
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$items = $order->get_items();

$product_id = 55; // that's a specific product ID

foreach ( $items as $item ) {

        if( $product_id == $item['product_id'] && $order->user_id ) {
            $user = new WP_User( $order->user_id );

            // Remove role
            $user->remove_role( 'customer' ); 

            // Add role
            $user->add_role( 'subscriber' );
        }

}

}
```

If you want to check by category, just add a condition with `has_term( $category_id, 'product_cat', $item['product_id'] )`

Comment: Great! Thank you so much